# Compute $\int_0^\infty \left(\frac{1}{x}\right)^{\ln(x)}\,\mathrm{d}x$

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

I want to compute the following integral to show that

$$ \int_0^\infty \left(\frac{1}{x}\right)^{\ln(x)}\,\mathrm{d}x=\mathrm{e}^{\frac{1}{4}}\sqrt{\pi}.$$ I have no idea where the $\sqrt{\pi}$ comes from.

Since the indefinite integral can't be evaluated with elementary functions I'm stuck.

I am just curious.

Comment: Maybe from $\Gamma(1/2)$.

Comment: Have you tried the substitution $x=e^y$?

Comment: Where are you seeing this integral?  In what context has it been presented?  Have you tried anything (there is a quick substitution which should make the integral easier to handle, for example)?  Do you know anything about complex integration (my first instinct is to use methods from complex analysis, though there is likely a more elementary approach which will work)?  Please edit your question to provide additional context.

Comment: This is a Gaussian integral after the substitution $x=e^t$. Look up the Wikipedia article or MSE for ways to evaluate: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_integral

Comment: Please let us know the context, was this a physical problem, an integration bee question, etc?

Comment: How did you stumble upon this integral? Also you can generalize it to:$$\int_0^\infty \left(\frac{a}{x^b}\right)^{c\ln x}dx=\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{bc}}\exp\left(\frac{(1+c\ln a)^2}{4bc}\right)$$
Just write $ f=e^{\ln f}$ followed by $\ln x=t$ and use the [generalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_integral#Generalizations) of the Gaussian integral.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It follows from the following reasoning:

Let $u = \log x \implies dx = e^u du$

$$\int_0^\infty x^{-\log x}\:dx = \int_{-\infty}^\infty (e^u)^{-u} e^u \:du = \int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-u^2 + u}du$$

$$ = \int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-\left(u-\frac{1}{2}\right)^2+\frac{1}{4}}du = e^{\frac{1}{4}} \int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-v^2}dv = e^{\frac{1}{4}} \sqrt{\pi}$$

by translating and then using the known value of the Gaussian integral.

Comment: You noted in a comment that the question was lacking context.  However, by providing an answer without waiting for the asker to provide additional context, you have discouraged the asker from improving their question.  In the future, it may be advisable to wait before posting a FGitW answer.

Comment: @XanderHenderson I understand your point but for me this problem was interesting enough for me to try. The question was not extra messy to the point where my choice on spending more time on it would've needed OP's context. Whether or not OP answers is none of my concern at this point, it was only to satisfy my intellectual curiosity, not to "improve the question". Having said that, I do have faith in OP in adjusting their post given their rep.

Comment: I also found the problem interesting.  For those users with over 10k XP, you will note that I, also, have answered this question (because it was a fun exercise).  However, I have deleted my answer until such time as the asker provides some context as, without that context, I don't think that this question (nor my answer) are of much use to the site.

Answer (score 6):

Substitute $x=e^{-t}$. That gives you $dx=-e^{-t}dt$. Hence, integral becomes $\int\limits_{\infty}^{-\infty}-(e^t)^{-t}e^{-t}dt$. Changin the integral to $\int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-t^2-t-0.25}e^{0.25}dt$. Substitute $t+0.5=v$ and the rest is standard.